# How to calculate symmetric difference in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, countif, google-sheets-query

I have two sets of values in columns **A:A** and **B:B**. I want to calculate [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between these two sets; i.e. get those values from **A:A** that do not exist in **B:B** and values from **B:B** that do not exist in **A:A**.

[image: See example of desired result]

So far I am using this and it works:

```
=FILTER({filter(A2:A,countif(B2:B,A2:A)=0);filter(B2:B,countif(A2:A,C2:C)=0)},{filter(A2:A,countif(B2:B,A2:A)=0);filter(B2:B,countif(A2:A,B2:B)=0)}<>"")
```

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 This can be made much simpler if there are guaranteed to not be duplicates WITHIN the A:A list or WITHIN the B:B list. Is that the case here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get those values from A:A that do not exist in B:B AND values from B:B that do not exist in A:A

```
=QUERY({
 FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B:B, A:A))); 
 FILTER(B:B, NOT(COUNTIF(A:A, B:B)))}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]